# Repair file detected as corrupted by System File Checker

Tags: windows-8.1, dism, sfc

I ran the `sfc /scannow` today on the system and it returned the following:

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix
>   some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log
>   %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.

The log contained the following info about corrupted file:

> 2015-08-28 02:08:50, Info                  CSI    000000ce [SR] Cannot
>   repair member file [l:18{9}]"Dism.psm1" of
>   Microsoft-Windows-Deployment-Image-Servicing-Management-Powershell,
>   Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9),
>   Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8
>   b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral
>   in the store, hash mismatch 2015-08-28 02:08:52, Info
>   CSI    000000d8 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:18{9}]"Dism.psm1" of
>   Microsoft-Windows-Deployment-Image-Servicing-Management-Powershell,
>   Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9),
>   Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8
>   b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral
>   in the store, hash mismatch 2015-08-28 02:08:52, Info
>   CSI    000000d9 [SR] This component was referenced by
>   [l:330{165}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base-Deployment"
>   2015-08-28 02:08:52, Info                  CSI    000000dc [SR] Could
>   not reproject corrupted file
>   [ml:520{260},l:118{59}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Dism"[l:18{9}]"Dism.psm1";
>   source file in store is also corrupted

Next I ran `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` which returned:

> C:\Windows\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
>
> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 6.3.9600.16384
>
> Image Version: 6.3.9600.16384
>
> [==========================100.0%==========================]
>
> Error: 2
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Does anyone have any idea about `Dism.psm1` file and how to repair this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `Dism.psm1` from the package `Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base` is corrupted.

I've extracted the package into a CAB. [Download it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/beko6ajcxlw4md6/Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.cab?dl=1), extract the CAB and point to it as source in the DISM command

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:C:\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384
```